# Eventlistener works for more than one object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, listener

so I've got this JavaSript/React code, and I've got these filerable scroll list components. I have an event listener in FilterableScrolLList.js bound to "document". Which, listens for an up or down arrow keypress, and then iterates through the list with those arrow presses. My issue is, some lists open up sublists, and when I try to use the arrow keys to move thru the sublist, they also move through the main list, closing the sublist. Is there anyway to get my code to only respond to the arrow clicks on my currently selected list?

Edit: Here is code example.

```
FilterableScrollList.js {
    let index = 0;
    componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleArrowKey);
        handleArrowKey {
            //Makes index go ++ or -- depending on up arrow or down arrow
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, this works on all filterable lists on the screen, and not just the one I have selected.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Impossible for u to answer with the information provided.